# If $f(x)$ is a positive valued function. $f(x)/f(x-1)=(x-2)/(x+1)$ for all $x\geq0,$ $f(6)=81,$ and $f(2)=4$ then find $f(4)$

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ is a positive valued function. $f(x)/f(x-1)=(x-2)/(x+1)$ for all $x\geq0,$ $f(6)=81,$ and $f(2)=4$ then find $f(4)$

Actually here the issue is  we can find f(4) with the help of f(6) alone but it will not match with options as the options given are a)8  b)18  c)25  d)28

Secondly if we put x= 2 in the given relation then right hand side becomes zero which which suggests that f(x) approaches infinity when x approaches 1 , hence it may contain 1/(x-1) , but how to make use of this . Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have typed the question correctly?

Comment: Exactly as it appeared in my exam

Comment: The best you can do is to move on from that question. You can try reporting the question to the exam board, but I am not sure how likely you are to succeed given your location.

Comment: Your idea about finding a formula for $f(x)$ is on the right track. Solving the recurrence relation by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%2Ff%28x-1%29+%3D+%28x-2%29%2F%28x%2B1%29) gives $f(x) = \frac{c_1}{x(x^2-1}$, and if you have a specific condition such as $f(2)=4$, you can find the value of $c_1$.

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of the question:

$$\frac{f(6)}{f(5)} = \frac{6-2}{6+1} \Rightarrow f(5) = \frac{567}{4}$$
$$\frac{f(5)}{f(4)} = \frac{5-2}{5+1} \Rightarrow f(4) = \frac{567}{2}$$

But we also have:

$$\frac{f(3)}{f(2)} = \frac{3-2}{3+1} \Rightarrow f(3)=1$$
$$\frac{f(4)}{f(3)} = \frac{4-2}{4+1} \Rightarrow f(4) = \frac{2}{5}$$

Therefore this function is poorly defined, so there is no way to answer the question.

Comment: Some more weirdness: plug in $x=2$ gives $4/f(1)=0/3$ which gives $4\cdot3=0\cdot f(1)$...